# API Access returns 'disabled' on Professional Edition + API Access addon

Tags: rest-api, professional-edition

I have access to several Salesforce Professional accounts with the API Access addon purchased.  I also have a Connected App which I've created which I've oauth'd with Users with System Administrator privileges from these accounts.

With one of the accounts, this works perfectly.  I can pull data via the REST API with no issues.

However, with some of the other accounts, I'm still receiving the error:

```
API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.
```

When trying to access the API.

From poking around inside all the accounts, I can't find any difference between them -- all the users who OAuth'd have Admin privileges, which should allow them to use the API.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the REST API is a separate permission on the blacktab and it seems like they forgot to enable that one for you. You will need to contact salesforce support to resolve this.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not able to access the SOAP API either (same error).  I do have a ticket open with Salesforce, so if this turns out to be the case, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: This is actually the answer we got (after getting the run-around) from our salesforce rep.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The ***API Add-On*** has always been a pain point with `PE` ... going way back to before `REST API` was even introduced. It's no surprise that it's problematic for you. It's almost completely undocumented as well.

Comment: Yes I've found this.  Salesforce closed our ticket telling us that `You can't get API access for professional edition`.  Then what did we just __pay__ for?

Comment: yeah see this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-there-any-documentation-about-using-client-id-token-with-rest-api-to-access?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Is the application for your own company/enterprise? 'Partner' with salesforce over the ISV program, clear the review and get listed on AppExchange. The cost is 300$ for the security review.

This would enable the APIs for all of CE, GE, PE accounts from the *application end*. At the end, you would be accessing the accounts using APIs through a namesake application.

This is one way you can bypass their plans and policies.