# Debug Log Application Unknown

Tags: rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, debug

We are developing iOS app which is using Salesforce iOS native SDK. We are currently using SFRestRequest class for communicate with SF. But in our "Debug Logs" it shows our log like this.

[image: Application Unknown]

Reqeust Type is Api which is okay. But in Application Field it says "Unknown" which can be difficult for us to track bugs. Is there any way to change this "Unknown" data to something like "iOS  app"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Partner API you can use the [CallOptions.value](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_calloptions.htm) to identify the client application. This populates the Application column. Or at least it does in the Login History view.

[image: Setting the Application via the CallOptions]

I don't think you can utilise this with the REST API, which is probably what backs the iOS Native SDK.

The same login using OAuth for a connected app also populates the Application field in the login details.

[image: OAuth Connect App]

I wasn't able to test this in the Debug logs as thee ApexSoap operations don't show up.

See also: [Is there any documentation about using Client ID / Token with REST API to access Group and Professional Editions?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/6/is-there-any-documentation-about-using-client-id-token-with-rest-api-to-access)